Hostinger Laravel Website not displaying errors
I have a project built with Laravel 9 and hosted on hostinger. Website is not loading and I cannot see error neither in laravel.log file nor on front end html page
I tried adding app debug true in .env file but its not working

Was it working earlier?

Yes, website was working fine earlier. no issue with configuration.

Please share more details. What did you change between the last working configuration and the current one? Did you check all log files for errors?

Just working with image upload dropzone.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If everything is working, what's the problem?

everything was working earlier when I deployed it to hostinger. Now I was working on file uploads using dropozone js and page does not load and I don't see error why its not loading correctly. In response it shows 500 error.

Please add all clarification to your question, including the relevant source code, the error message from your server's log, and your attempts to resolve the problem

You need to enable displayErrors and logErrors in PHP Configuration option for hostinger if that's not enabled.
Go to Websites -> Advanced (PHP Configuration) option and there will be a tab labeled as PHP Options. Look for displayErrors and logErrors checkbox and enable both of those. It will show error on front-end and will log them too.
I had faced same error.
For reference look into this article. It solves this issue:
https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/4259219-how-to-display-php-error-messages

Let me check this.
